# Regex for string with \n in java

Tags: java, regex

```java
public static boolean regexPattern(String string) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}.\\d{2} \\w+\n");
        return pattern.matcher(string).matches();
    }

String value = "11:20 morning\n" + "11:30 morning\n";
System.out.println(filtersByRegex.regexPattern(value));
```

The above method returns 'false' every time. Someone can help me fix this?

p.s.: I've tried to deal with: [\r-\n], Pattern.DOTALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind `.matches()` attempts to match the full String (as the documentation states). But your regex matches only a single line at a time. If you want to check if the String at some point has a matching result, you should use `.find()`. It will return `true` because there is at least one match. If you want to look for two lines with the same date you should go for a pattern like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}.\\d{2} \\w+\\n\\d{2}.\\d{2} \\w+\\n");
```

This could be improved, but the gist is that.